# R Shiny - How to create a barplot that reacts according to the time unit (Week, Month, Year) and aggregates data by time unit

Tags: r, date, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I generate a dataframe about a disease with the following variables:

- Date (date of disease)
- Cases (number of cases, by default, the number of cases is 1)
- Week (week of disease case)
- Month (month of disease case)
- Year (year of disease case).

My ui is here:

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

Disease<-data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2017/1/1"), "days"),Cases=rep(1))
Disease$Week<-as.Date(cut(Disease$Date,breaks="week",start.on.monday = TRUE))
Disease$Month<-as.Date(cut(Disease$Date,breaks="month"))
Disease$Year<-as.Date(cut(Disease$Date,breaks="year"))

ui <- fluidPage(
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Choice the date",
      start = min(Disease$Date),
      end = max(Disease$Date),
      min = min(Disease$Date),
      max = max(Disease$Date),
      separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
      startview = 'Month', language = 'fr', weekstart = 1),
      selectInput(inputId = 'Time_unit',
      label='Time_unit',
      choices=c('Week','Month','Year'),
      selected='Month'),
plotOutput("Disease"))
```

I wish to create a barplot that reacts according to the time unit (i.e. week, month, year) and that agregates data by time unit

You will  find below the code of the server (but it doesn't work) :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
       dateRangeInput<-reactive({
       dataset= subset(Disease, Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= 
       input$daterange[2])
       return(dataset)
       })
selectInput= reactive({
summarize(group_by(dateRangeInput(),
period = switch(input$Time_unit,
"Week"=Disease$Week,
"Month" = Disease$Month,
"Year" = Disease$Year)))
})

output$Disease <-renderPlot({
ggplot(data=selectInput(), aes_string(x="period",x="Cases"))  
+ stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar") 
+ labs(title="Disease", y ="Number of cases")
+theme_classic() 
+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
})

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will find below barplots thatI would like to obtain if I choose Week or Month or Year:

- by Month: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWoL.png
- by Week: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAWJq.png

Sorry for "by Year", I can't to post more than 2 links

Comment: I forgot to say : Hello !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this code out, it is working how You want:

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

Disease<-data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2017/1/1"), "days"),Cases=rep(1))
Disease <- Disease %>% mutate(Week = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%U"),Month = format(Date, "%Y-%m"), Year = format(Date, "%Y"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Choice the date",
                 start = min(Disease$Date),
                 end = max(Disease$Date),
                 min = min(Disease$Date),
                 max = max(Disease$Date),
                 separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                 startview = 'Month', language = 'fr', weekstart = 1),
  selectInput(inputId = 'Time_unit',
              label='Time_unit',
              choices=c('Week','Month','Year'),
              selected='Month'),
  plotOutput("Disease"))


server <- function(input, output) {
  dateRangeInput<-reactive({
    dataset <- subset(Disease, Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2])
    dataset
  })
  selectInput= reactive({
    dataset <- dateRangeInput() %>% group_by_(input$Time_unit) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Cases))
    print(head(dataset))
    dataset
    })

  output$Disease <-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=selectInput(), aes_string(x=input$Time_unit,y="Sum"))  + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    labs(title="Disease", y ="Number of cases") +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  })

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Plot is reactive to the `Time_unit` input, You just need to do small adjustment with the axis text and thats it.

P.S. Your second link to the image

> by Week

is not working --> getting an empty space.

Comment: Dear Malvina_a, it's perfect. I thank you for your help. Sorry for the image.   I have a last question if it's possible. If I wish to make a stacked barplot, that is mean, with two variables (for exemple, the imported case number and the autpchtonous case number), according to you, how I can code it : dataset <- dateRangeInput() %>% group_by_(input$Time_unit) %>% summarise(Sum1 = sum(Imported_Cases), Sum2=sum(Autochtonous_Cases ) ? Thank you for advance.

Comment: Yes You should do it exactly how you wrote, however to create a stacked bar plot, You must 'melt' the data after calculation of 'sum's and created variable use as a fill argument in 'ggplot'

Comment: @ Malvina_ a. Great ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Pascal i think You should ask a new question if You are having a problems with `melt` function

Comment: Hi Malvina_a, ok, thank you, I will post  a new question with "melt" function on the forum. I prepare that.