# R Shiny - How to use the "melt" function (reshape2 package) to create a stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr, reshape2

thanks to your answers, I managed to make a barplot that reacts according to the time unit (Week, Month, Year) and agregates data by time unit (the link is here) :
[R Shiny - How to create a barplot that reacts according to the time unit (Week, Month, Year) and agregates data by time unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673455/r-shiny-how-to-create-a-barplot-that-reacts-according-to-the-time-unit-week)

Then, I wish to make a stacked barplot with two variables. For it, I generate the follow data frame with two variables (i.e. in my example: Imported_cases  and Autochthonous_cases) and I apply the “melt” function. The UI is here :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

Disease <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2017/1/1"), "days"),
  Imported_cases = rep(1),Autochtonous_cases=rep(2))
Disease <- Disease %>% mutate(
  Week = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%U"),
  Month = format(Date, "%Y-%m"), Year = format(Date, "%Y"))
Disease<- melt(Disease, id = c("Date","Week","Month","Year"), 
               measured = c("Imported_cases", "Autochtonous_cases"))
print(head(Disease))

ui <- fluidPage(
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Choice the date",
                     start = min(Disease$Date),
                     end   = max(Disease$Date),
                     min   = min(Disease$Date),
                     max   = max(Disease$Date),
                     separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                     startview = 'Month', language = 'fr', weekstart = 1),
      selectInput(inputId = 'Time_unit',
                  label = 'Time_unit',
                  choices = c('Week', 'Month', 'Year'),
                  selected = 'Month'),
                  plotOutput("Disease"))
```

When I run my server, R Shiny displays : Error object 'variable' not found. You find bellow the server code :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
dateRangeInput <- reactive({
dataset <- subset(
  Disease, Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2])
dataset
})

selectInput = reactive({
dataset <- dateRangeInput() %>% group_by_(input$Time_unit) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(value))
dataset
})

output$Disease <-renderPlot({
                ggplot(data=selectInput(), 
                aes_string(x = input$Time_unit, y = "Sum", 
                           fill = "variable"))  + 
                geom_bar(stat = "identity")
                })

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't know if the problem is the code of `selectInput` or the code of `output$Disease`. I don't understand why Shiny doesn't find "variable" (cf. print(head(Disease)). Thank you for your help (I hope to be clear).

Comment: I forgot to say : Hello !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hier is code which is going to work and create the stacked bar plot:

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

Disease<-data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2017/1/1"), "days"),Cases=rep(1),Autochtonous_cases=rep(2))
Disease <- Disease %>% mutate(Week = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%U"),Month = format(Date, "%Y-%m"), Year = format(Date, "%Y"))
Disease<-melt(Disease,id=c("Date","Week","Month","Year")) # just id


ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Choice the date",
                 start = min(Disease$Date),
                 end = max(Disease$Date),
                 min = min(Disease$Date),
                 max = max(Disease$Date),
                 separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                 startview = 'Month', language = 'fr', weekstart = 1),
  selectInput(inputId = 'Time_unit',
              label='Time_unit',
              choices=c('Week','Month','Year'),
              selected='Month'),
  plotOutput("Disease"))


server <- function(input, output) {
  dateRangeInput<-reactive({
    dataset <- subset(Disease, Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2])
    dataset
  })
  selectInput= reactive({
    dataset <- dateRangeInput() %>% group_by_(input$Time_unit,"variable") %>% summarise(Sum = sum(value)) #I have added here grouping as variable
    print(head(dataset))
    dataset
  })

  output$Disease <-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=selectInput(), aes_string(x=input$Time_unit,y="Sum", fill = "variable"))  + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      labs(title="Disease", y ="Number of cases") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  })

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I guess this is what You are looking for. You had small mistakes in `melt` function, setting up only id variables is fair enough, second thing is to consider the created variable column in `group_by_` (as You wanna get the count of cases and autochtonous cases), and last is using variable as an `fill` argument in `ggplot`.

Comment: To Malvina_a. I sincerely thank you. Now, I understand my mistakes  (just id for melt function and  group_by_(.....,"variable"). It's exactly what I want. I hope your answers will help other people. Thanks a lot. Pascal